# SQLite UPDATE statement gets Fatal Exception

Tags: android, sqlite

I get this exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ".": syntax error: , while compiling: UPDATE items SET I.red='1' FROM items I, feeds F  WHERE I.feedLink=F.link AND F.category='Genel'
```

from this statement:

```
UPDATE items 
SET I.red='1' 
FROM items I, feeds F 
WHERE I.feedLink=F.link AND F.category='Genel'
```

using SQLite in Android. How can I solve this?

> **Note**: items and feeds are names of my datebase tables.

Comment: There's no such query - UPDATE ... FROM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL UPDATE syntax:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

To hone in on what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```
UPDATE items 
SET red='1' 
WHERE feedLink IN 
(SELECT link FROM feeds WHERE category='Genel')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

UPDATE items i SET i.red='1' FROM items i, feeds f WHERE i.feedLink=f.link AND f.category='Genel'

If that does not do it try breaking it into two queries:

SELECT f.link FROM feeds f WHERE f.category='Genel'

And then use the result from that in the following query:

UPDATE items i SET i.red='1' WHERE i.feedLink IN ([f.link(s) in the result from the prev. query])

Comment: Declare the table name shortcut at both places where items is spelled and also use lowercase i&f instead of I&F.

Comment: Yes? That is not what I am doing here.

Comment: Sorry, you're almost right. The WHERE statement should say i.feedLink IN.